# how to scrape some text inside an href randomly generated - selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I was scraping a dynamic page with selenium and I got stuck getting **text 1** and **text 2** in the following example:

`<span class="class number 1"> text 1 <a href="link 1"> text 2 </a> </span>`

The same happens if the span is instead a div.

---

I managed to get text 1 with this python line

`var = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class number 1").text"`

However, to get text 2, since link 1 is generated, say, randomly, I can't refer to the href in any way!

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS Selectors

```
txt2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='class number 1'] > a").text
```

#To extract both text node values at the same time, you can use `innerHTML` as follows

```
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='class number 1'].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it retrieves 'text 2':

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='class number 1']/a").text
```